# Convert object to multi-dimensional array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, type-conversion

I have an object like this:

```
var myObj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: 4
};
```

And i want to convert that object to a multi-dimensional array like this:

```
var myArray = [['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3], ['d', 4]];
```

How could i achieve this?

Comment: `var arr = Object.keys(myObj).map(k => [k, myObj[k]]);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries` function.

```js
var myObj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 },
    myArray = Object.entries(myObj);
    
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myArray));
```

...or `Object.keys` and `Array#map` functions.

```js
var myObj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 },
    myArray = Object.keys(myObj).map(v => new Array(v, myObj[v]));
    
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myArray));
```

Comment: *NOTE*: Object.entries is not ubiquitously implemented - it is still experimental. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Comment: You saved my life!, I didn't remember it!

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myArray = [];
var myObj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 };
for(var key in myObj) {
  myArray.push([key, myObj[key]]);
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(myArray));
```